# Put footer with 100% width after one div with 100% width

Tags: html, css

Im just trying to put my footer exactly below one div with 100% width but if I use position:absolute its not going to be 100% width.

```
    .box {
    width:100%;
    left:0%;
    height:700px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:6%;
    background-image:url();
    background-position-y:90%;
    background-position-x:50%;
}

.footer {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    width:100%;
    height:90px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-30%;
    left:0%;
    box-shadow:0px -5px 0px 0px #c72031;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="footer"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/opj984j7/

Comment: Can you add your html ?

Comment: Include your HTML so we can see what you trying to do.

Comment: You need to provide a simple working example. Why do you position the element absolute anyway? If it should be directly after another element, which is not positioned absolute?

Comment: Done, check right now

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/opj984j7/

@ShaigKhaligli

Comment: It think you don`t need position absolute anymore. Float:left will do the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the footer inside the box and give it `bottom: 0;` to display without any margin from the bottom. Or to display below, reduce `bottom` of the footers height `bottom: -90px;`:

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0%;
  height: 700px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 6%;
  background: #000;
}
.footer {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -90px;
  left: 0%;
  box-shadow: 0px -5px 0px 0px #c72031;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It wasnt an empty background url, i just removed the destination. But you add an background the footer gonna be in the middle of it.

Comment: It worked, thank you! Thought I cant put it under the another div.

Comment: You actually can, updated my answer again. But maybe in your case, the absolute positioning isn't necessary anymore? If so, you can just use the normal float of the elements to display the footer underneath.

Answer (score 0):

> ***Absolute Position:*** This is a very powerful type of positioning that allows you
>   to literally place any page element exactly where you want it. You use
>   the positioning attributes top, left bottom and right to set the
>   location. Remember that these values will be relative to the next
>   parent element with relative (or absolute) positioning. If there is no
>   such parent, it will default all the way back up to the  element
>   itself meaning it will be placed relatively to the page itself. The
>   trade-off, and most important thing to remember, about absolute
>   positioning is that these elements are removed from the flow of
>   elements on the page. An element with this type of positioning is not
>   affected by other elements and it doesn't affect other elements. This
>   is a serious thing to consider every time you use absolute
>   positioning. It's overuse or improper use can limit the flexibility of
>   your site.

An element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed).

However; if an absolute positioned element has no positioned ancestors, it uses the document body, and moves along with page scrolling.